# Add line break "\n" to UITextView but not work

Tags: objective-c

As per subject, my code as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // Add Scroll View
    CGRect fullScreenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
    self.view = scrollView;

    // Configure Scroll View
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);

    // Shop Detail
    CGRect shopDetailFrame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 300, 80);
    UITextView *shopDetail = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:shopDetailFrame] autorelease];
    shopDetail.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    shopDetail.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    NSString *shopName = @"Shop A, G/F, 1/F-3/F, Lok Sing Building, 16 Kau Yuk Road";
    shopDetail.text = [[shopName stringByAppendingString:@"\n"] stringByAppendingString:shopName];
    [scrollView addSubview:shopDetail];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Suppose the output is:

```
Shop A, G/F, 1/F-3/F, Lok Sing Building, 16 Kau Yuk Road
Shop A, G/F, 1/F-3/F, Lok Sing Building, 16 Kau Yuk Road
```

But I got:

```
Shop A, G/F, 1/F-3/F, Lok Sing Building, 16 Kau Yuk Road...
```

The `\n` not work on UITextView, anyone know how to make line break on UITextView?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this line:

```
UITextView *shopDetail = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:shopDetailFrame] autorelease];
```

You're creating a UILabel instead of a UITextView.

You can still use a UILabel, but by default it will only show a single line. To make a UILabel show more lines, you need to set the `numberOfLines` property to either `0` (for no limit) or the number of lines you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `\n` programmatically, it works.

```
var txt_Other_Proj = String()
txt_Other_Proj = "Other Jessit Apps and Projects"
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "\n"
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "Hurkle: A FIND ME game"
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "\n"
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "A free game."
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "\n"
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "Candida Cookbook"
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "\n"
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "Living with Candida Albicans"
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "\n"
txt_Other_Proj = txt_Other_Proj + "Visit www.Jessit.com"

main_Info.text = txt_Other_Proj
```